# Return an integer encoding of the position

Tags: python, oop

The function `to_integer()` must replace the colours of the points (Empty=".", White="O", Black="@") of the Go board by digits (empty=0, white=1, black=2) and concatenate all rows of the board to a single row of digits which gives a ternary number that can then be converted to an integer.

```
   A B C
 3 O . O
 2 . @ .
 1 @ O .
```

... which should give 101020210.

For now, my code is as such, but it doesn't give that output and I used a dictionary to extract the value according to the symbol:

```py
points = {
    'E': '.',
    'B': '@',
    'W': 'O'
}

to_integer ={
    '.': '0',
    'O': '1',
    '@': '2'
}   

 def to_integer(self):
        digit_colour=""
        for line in self.to_strings():
            for character in line:
                print(character)
                character = "'" + character + "'"
                print(character)
                num_colour = self.to_integer.values(character)
                digit_colour += num_colour
        digit_colour = int(digit_colour)
        return digit_colour

b = Board(
   3,
   ["O.O", ".@.", "@O."]
)
print(b.to_integer())
```

How can I get the desired output?

the code overall:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters

class Board:

   #Dictionary created for the colours and the respected symbols
      points = {'E': '.', 'B': '@', 'W': 'O'}
      to_int={'.':'0','O':'1','@':'2'}
#Constructor
    def __init__(self,size=19,from_strings=None):
        assert 2 <= size <= 26, "Illegal board size: must be between 2 and 26."
        assert type(from_strings) is list,"input is not a list"
        assert len(from_strings)==size, "length of input list does not match size"
        for i in from_strings:
             assert type(i)==str, "row "+i+" is not a string"
             assert len(i)==size,"length of row "+i+" does not match size"
             #assert i == self.grid[i], "invalid character in row "+i
        self.size = size
        self.grid = [['E'] * size for _ in range(size)]
        self.from_strings = [] if from_strings is None else from_strings
    
   def __str__(self):  # creating the grid
         padding = ' '  # Creating a variable with a space assigned so that it acts as a padding to the rows that have a single digit
         heading = '   ' + ' '.join(letters[:self.size])  # Alphabetical heading is created
         lines = [heading]  # adding the alphabetical heading into a list named lines to which the rows will be added later
         for r, row in enumerate(self.grid):
                if len(self.grid) < 10:  # for the grid with a size less than 10 to add the space to the start of the row for the single digits to be aligned
                     if (self.from_strings):
                            line = " " + f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.from_strings[r])
                     else:
                            line = " " + f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.points[x] for x in row)
            lines.append(line)
                 else:  # for the grids that are larger than 9
                          if r > 9:  # for rows 1 to 9 the single digits are aligned according to the first digit from the right of the two digit rows
                               if (self.from_strings):
                                     line = f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.from_strings[r])
                               else:
                                     line = f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.points[x] for x in row)
                               line = padding + line  # adding the space using the variable padding to the row created
                               lines.append(line)  # adding the row to the list of rows
                          else:  # for the rows 10 onwards - as there is no requirement to add a padding it is not added here
                              if (self.from_strings):
                                    line = f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.from_strings[r])
                              else:
                                    line = f'{self.size - r} ' + ' '.join(self.points[x] for x in row)  # creation of the row
                              lines.append(line)  # adding the newly created row to the list of rows
        return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: please give us code that can run

Comment: You can use a single string `pieces = '.O@'` and then something like `pieces.index('O')` will return the corresponding integer you want.

Comment: You have a dict called `to_integer` but also a function called `to_integer` so their names will conflict with each other

Comment: What is the point of your `points` dictionary? The symbols used in the board seem to already be `.0@` so you don't need to convert to that.

Comment: does `self.strings` look like `["O.O", ".@.", "@O."]`? More details would help.

Comment: Without knowing the complete `Board` class definition, it is pretty hard to understand the code snippet you posted.

Comment: I've updated the post with more of the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Try to edit the post to show the code in a more coherent way, and show **only** the parts that are needed to replicate the problem. For example, if we do not need to `print` out a `Board` instance in order to understand the problem, then we should not have a `__str__` method. On the other hand, if `to_integer` is intended to be a method of the `Board` class, then show it **within that class**.  In general, we should be able to **copy and paste** the code from the question, run it, and **directly** see the **exact** problem.

Comment: Please also indent code consistently (since the question does not appear to be about indentation), and explain clearly **what is wrong** - that is: "How can I get the desired output?" well, **what is** the desired output? What output **do you get instead**, and **how is that different**?

Comment: Also, show **one** code block if at all possible. The current code is a mess, because the first code block shows a lookup dict named `to_integer` that seems to have been an attempt to reproduce `to_int` from inside the `Board` class. This sort of thing **is a source of typos and misleading stray problems** that are not related to the question. In particular, trying to name that `dict` as `to_integer`, when the conversion method is **also** named `to_integer` *in the same context*, will obviously cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

A succinct way to do it is with a single join:

```
codes ={
    '.': '0',
    'O': '1',
    '@': '2'
}

def board_to_int(board):
    return ''.join(codes[c] for line in board for c in line)
```

For example

```
board = ["O.O", ".@.", "@O."]
print(board_to_int(board))
#101020210
```

In case you are curious, `int(board_to_int(board),3)` gives you the base 10 representation of this ternary number, which in this example is `7473`.